# clojure list operation result not equal

Tags: clojure

I test some list operation, find this difference with two syntax。

```
(conj (cons 321321 [1]) 123123123)
=> (123123123 321321 1)
```

and

```
(cons 321321 [1])
=> (321321 1)
(conj [321312 1] 123123123)
=> [321312 1 123123123]
```

why these result isn't equal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are doing different things.

`cons` http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cons

> Returns a new seq where x is the first element and seq is
>     the rest.

`conj` http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj

> Returns a new collection with the xs
>     'added'. (conj nil item) returns (item).  **The 'addition' may
>     happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type.**

in your first example you are "prepending" a new entry (easiest way for conj to add to a sequence) and in your second example you are "appending" to a vector (again easiest way for conj to add).

```
user=> (.getClass (cons 321321 [1]))
clojure.lang.Cons
user=> (.getClass (conj (cons 321321 [1]) 123123123))
clojure.lang.Cons
```

Note you are using `[...]` next!

```
user=> (.getClass [321312 1])
clojure.lang.PersistentVector
user=> (.getClass (conj [321312 1] 123123123))
clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

Comment: Thanks，(conj (seq [1 2 3]) 4),this example is your explan